# What's the icon needed for Cortana's Help list?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, voice-recognition, cortana

So I'm adding voice command recognitions with Cortana in my app. My VCD file is all set and everything is working as expected, so now I have to look for the little things.

I have all the needed icons (that I know of) in my app but still when my app appears on the Cortana screen (the "What can I say?" screen), my app appears with a default icon, not added by me.

So my question is, what's the missing icon I'm not seeing?

[image]

p.s: the official Remote Desktop app also shows the same icon so I guess I'm not the only one with the missing icon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, according to [Rob Caplan](https://twitter.com/robcap) it is known issue in [windows-phone-8.1](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8.1) Runtime apps.

> This is a known problem with Windows Phone Runtime apps which doesn't affect Silverlight apps. There isn't anything you can do to alter this from your code. We are looking into a fix for future updates of the OS.

source: [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f326d39e-81b5-4fcb-829d-3611383c1948/)