# Windows Phone 8.1 Cortana App Icon

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app that supports voice commands. When I launch cortana, it shows a list of apps that can be launched as examples. It lists my app, but shows a different app icon which is not even defined in my manifest.

I have all visual assets defined in Package.appxmanifest. So my question is this - is there a way to change the icon which shows up next to your app in Cortana?

Comment: platform bugzz

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550963/whats-the-icon-needed-for-cortanas-help-list?rq=1